# How to do HEVC transcoding from USB webcam using Intel HD Graphics 4600 GPU?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, graphics-card, encoding, intel-graphics

I am trying to use hardware acceleration using Intel GPU.

Trying to do so basic testing and it seems ffmpeg does not allow hardware acceleration to take place even though supported. Not sure what the issue is.

Trying to transcode a USB webcam stream from MJPG decoding to HEVC encoding.

PC Details:

- **OS**: Arch Linux x86_64
- **Kernel**: 5.18.12-arch1-1
- **Resolution**: 1920x1080
- **CPU**: Intel i5-4570 (4) @ 3.600GHz (Haswell) (Released June-2013)
- **GPU**: Intel HD Graphics
- **Memory**: 565MiB / 3814MiB

Here is some basic encoding FFMPEG command which does not work:

```
ffmpeg -i video_sample.mp4 -c:v hevc_qsv -preset 7 output.mp4 -y

ffmpeg version n5.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video_sample.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:40.87, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9392 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p(pc, gbr/bt709/iec61966-2-1), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9391 kb/s, 30.02 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> hevc (hevc_qsv))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[hevc_qsv @ 0x559d32fee840] Error initializing an internal MFX session: unsupported (-3)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

What could be issue?

FWIW, it seems like Haswell CPUs does not have HEVC embedded transcoding.

However I get the same exact error for when trying to encode H.264.
Haswell CPUs does have H.264 embedded transcoding.

Comment: Pretty sure hardware encoding with a baked in GPU like that will result in garbage. I have a MacBook Air and when I attempt hardware encoding with the Apple’s T2 chip the result are utter garbage compared to simply doing it all software-based.

Comment: In Windows `ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -c:v h264_qsv -preset 7 output.mp4 -y` is working even with Core i5-3550. It could be that FFmpeg for Linux supports QuickSync with Gen 5 and above (due to drives issues).